# Access variables/functions from another Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im trying to change a variable in another script by touching a cube.
Current setup

- 1x Player
- 1x Enemy

Each with their own script `Enemy_Stats` & `Character_Stats`
As you can see in this little snippet it's quite a workaround to access the variable from another script.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy_Stats>().Health = 
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy_Stats>().Health 
            - gameObject.GetComponent<Character_Stats>().AttackDamage;

        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy_Stats>().Health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Iam new to Unity, but isn't there a way to just refer it with something like:
`collision.Health`?

Comment: no, since its a collision and not enemy_stats. you wouldnt expect an apple to taste like an orange either.

Comment: you MUST NOT use Character_Stats as a name.  it would be CharacterStats.  Same for the others.

Comment: even if it doesnt comply with language standards it wont cause errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to access variables/functions from another Class. The variable or function you want to access or called must be `public` not `private`.

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour{

    public int playerScore = 0;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void doSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

Access variable `playerScore` in `ScriptA` from `ScriptB`. First, find the GameObject that the script or component is attached to with the `GameObject.Find` function then use the `GetComponent` function to retrieve that script or component that is attached to it.

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour{

    ScriptA scriptInstance = null;  

    void Start()
    {
      GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectScriptAIsAttachedTo");
      scriptInstance = tempObj.GetComponent<ScriptA>();

      //Access playerScore variable from ScriptA
      scriptInstance.playerScore = 5;

     //Call doSomething() function from ScriptA
      scriptInstance.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better than using `Find` and `GetComponent` often is to simply make `[SerializeField] ScriptA scriptInstance;` and reference it via the Unity Inspector by drag&drop

Answer (score 2):

No since `Health` is not part of the collision object, but `Enemy_Stats`. You can cache a `Component` (that's what Enemy_Stats is) if you use it multiple times to save you some typing (and some performance, but that is rather marginal for this example). Also you can cache "known" components like in this case `Player_Stats`. You can do this e.g. in `Start` or with a public variable and the inspector.

What you should probably do though is to make the enemy be responsible for his life and not the player, so move the `Destroy`-part to `Enemy_Stats` (into the Health property to be exact).

Comment: Correct.  Simon, what you must do is this:  `collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyStats>().TakeDamage(stats.doesDamage)`

Comment: write the routine `TakeDamage` as you see fit.

Comment: you MUST change Enemy_Stats to EnemyStats.  note that you have "AttackDamage" etc with capitals.  Unless you are actually using properties, they must be lower case

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to make this shorter (and eventually faster) would be to store this: `gameObject.GetComponent<Character_Stats>()` on `Start()` in a private variable (you should avoid calling GetComponent on a frequent basis if you can avoid it).

For the Health variable, a way of avoiding `GetComponent` calls could be caching: you create a `Dictionary<GameObject, Enemy_Stats>` and read from that as soon as this gameobject collided once

Comment: the last part there: you can't, really, cache in that manner in games ... shit changes too much, components come and go etc.  you just have to do o a lookup, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning i mean in  `Awake()` method you can find a `game-object with tag`
and get it's `Heath`  after that in `Collision()`  method you should just `decrease the health` but, here the condition is there is only one enemy and only one player.