# Get the position of a gameobject in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am using this script to sort an array alphanumeric:

```
public class AlphanumComparatorFast : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string s1 = x as string;
        if (s1 == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        string s2 = y as string;
        if (s2 == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int len1 = s1.Length;
        int len2 = s2.Length;
        int marker1 = 0;
        int marker2 = 0;

        // Walk through two the strings with two markers.
        while (marker1 < len1 && marker2 < len2)
        {
            char ch1 = s1[marker1];
            char ch2 = s2[marker2];

            // Some buffers we can build up characters in for each chunk.
            char[] space1 = new char[len1];
            int loc1 = 0;
            char[] space2 = new char[len2];
            int loc2 = 0;

            // Walk through all following characters that are digits or
            // characters in BOTH strings starting at the appropriate marker.
            // Collect char arrays.
            do
            {
                space1[loc1++] = ch1;
                marker1++;

                if (marker1 < len1)
                {
                    ch1 = s1[marker1];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (char.IsDigit(ch1) == char.IsDigit(space1[0]));

            do
            {
                space2[loc2++] = ch2;
                marker2++;

                if (marker2 < len2)
                {
                    ch2 = s2[marker2];
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (char.IsDigit(ch2) == char.IsDigit(space2[0]));

            // If we have collected numbers, compare them numerically.
            // Otherwise, if we have strings, compare them alphabetically.
            string str1 = new string(space1);
            string str2 = new string(space2);

            int result;

            if (char.IsDigit(space1[0]) && char.IsDigit(space2[0]))
            {
                int thisNumericChunk = int.Parse(str1);
                int thatNumericChunk = int.Parse(str2);
                result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk);
            }
            else
            {
                result = str1.CompareTo(str2);
            }

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
}
```

And this is my script with the array which is attached to all the cubes:

```
void Awake()
{
    allCubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
    allCubes = allCubes.OrderBy(obj => obj.name, new AlphanumComparatorFast()).ToArray();
}
```

This is the output in the inspector:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/0dd2c9fdf8e07f9f971cd074695fc061.png]

My question is: is there a way to find out at what number the current object in the array is? I added this script to all the cubes, so is there a way that if I put some code in the script it will return the position of that gameobject in the array list? For example if I debug Cube5, it will return:

> My position in the array is 4

My goal with this is to get the next cube of the next cube of each cube :).
So Cube1 should give me Cube3, Cube3 should give me Cube5 etc.. I thought I could just use the answer and then do that `variable + 2`. I want this, because each cube has to get some information of the next cube of the next cube.

Comment: It sounds like you want to maintain a linked list, it would be orders of magnitude faster depending on your final implementation and whether it's possible to link the cubes by reference when you create them. You can probably just loop over the cubes returned by `FindGameObjects` and set up the references there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over the array and compare the GameObject instance. If it matches, return the current loop index. If nothing matches, return a negative number since array cannot have a negative number.

```
public GameObject[] allCubes;

int findIndex(GameObject target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allCubes.Length; i++)
    {
        //If we find the index return the current index
        if (allCubes[i] == target)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    //Nothing found. Return a negative number
    return -1;
}
```

To use in your scrip, pass the `gameObject` variable to it which will get the current GameObject this script is attached to.

```
int index = findIndex(gameObject);
```

---

**EDIT:**

I suggest you change your current design a little-bit and put that code in your question on an empty GameObject so that the `AlphanumComparatorFast`  script is executed once. You can then access that array result from your other scrips. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341408/access-variables-functions-from-another-script) post for how to do that. I am saying this because it will speed up your game.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Np. Modified my answer to show how you can improve what you have now. Read from **EDIT** down. Don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already did that before. Actually I just put it into a seperate script but I didn't attach it to anything, but it still works. Is that possible?

Comment: Nope. You have to attach it to a GameObject. An empty GameObject is fine. See the link in my answer for how to access it.

Comment: In Unity, if you want to access a script from another script, you must attach that script to a GameObject. See [Unity Project Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) to learn more about Unity.

Comment: I know I know, but I haven't done that however it still changed the array.

Comment: What o you mean by "it still changed the array"? Are you having a mew problem?

Comment: Forget about that, I forgot to ask something: I use this to get the next of the next cube of each cube ''int index = findIndex(gameObject) + 2;'', now I do I get the relevant gameObject by the index? So if I use this code at Cube2, orginally it would say ''Cube2 is number 1'' but it is +2 so it says 'Cube2 is number 3". How do I get the gameObject of that number 3? So in short: how to get the gameObject of "int index = findIndex(gameObject) + 2;"

Comment: Ummm. Just get the index then use that index to access the element? `int index = findIndex(gameObject) + 2`...`GameObject next2Objects = allCubes[index]`..... You should also check if `index` is `<` the `allCubes.Length-1` before doing that last part.

Comment: Ofcourse.... that is really easy and I know that.. I was just thinking too hard.. thanks a lot for all the help you saved a lot of time :) But why ''You should also check if index is < the allCubes.Length-1 before doing that last part."? I normally don't do that.

Comment: Just found out why. Thanks :)

Comment: You will likely get an index error because you are accessing index that's not available.

Comment: Note that you have not accepted this answer. There is a difference between upvoting and accepting answers.  See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for how to do so.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, because I clicked it and it said ''wait 5 minutes before you can accept as answer". You can see the result of your help in this video :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR9AAn1OMfw

Comment: Np. Your video is set to private so I can't see it.

Comment: Whoops. I wanted to set it as hidden. It is fixed now.

Comment: This is great, but why not use the built-in `ArrayUtility.IndexOf(T[] array, T object)` instead?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ArrayUtility.IndexOf.html

Comment: @Felype Don't suggest that. It's from the UnityEditor namespace and won't compile outside the Editor.

Comment: .NET Framework supports this https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx since .net 2.0 and I'm pretty sure Mono also does. Again, it is not necessary to reimplement something that is already implemented.

Comment: @Felype No one is saying that it is necessary to re-implement something that is already implemented. This answer explains how to do stuff OP wanted to do and not how to use an already existing API. You comments are **not** useful. It would have been if you just put something like this *"You can also use `Array.IndexOf`"* but you did not. You went from suggesting `ArrayUtility.IndexOf` which you can't use into talking about using .NET library but did not admit that you can't use `ArrayUtility.IndexOf` making others more likely to use that. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer Yep, it's the fog effect (sorry for late reply)