# Calling a script from another GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am programming on C#. I have a gameobject that contains two different scripts. 1) PlayerController 2) PlayerHealth.

When I try to call PlayerHealth using the code below

```
if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().currentHealth <= 25);
{
transform.position = startTarget.transform.position;
}
```

the code above does not work. But when I use the same code on another Gameobject that contains only one script, it works.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

I used this code to check if it reads the script

```
GameObject playerHealthObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); 
if (playerHealthObject != null) 
{ 
  playerHealth = playerHealthObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>(); 
} 
if (playerHealth == null) 
{ 
  Debug.Log("Cannot find 'Script' playerHealth"); 
}
```

And I get that it can not find the script while am sure of the Gameobject Tag and the script name.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ? What happens and what should happen ?

Comment: I edited the code. I mean the gameobject does not transform to startTarget position.

Comment: I assume that you mean "does not work" = "does not enter the `if` block" ?

Comment: Can't you use the debugger to see what's inside of the `currentHealth` var ? This might help you understand what's wrong

Comment: I get around this by defining player as Public and got the component directly from it.
`playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();`

It's the only way it worked for me.

Comment: Your question has been marked as a duplicate. You just described what is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341573/6838730) from the thread your is identical to.

Comment: yea, I saw that after trying to answer my Question. But it is definitely not what I used in my code. Using the answer from the thread, did not work with me. It only works with GameObjects that contains one script. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you fixed it ! Good luck coding :-)

Comment: *"It only works with GameObjects that contains one script."* This doesn't make any sense. `GetComponent` can find any component regardless of how much script is attached to that Object. The only difference between your "working code" and the one from my answer is that you are checking for `null`. There is no reason why that shouldn't work with any component. In the future when you try an answer and it doesn't work, update your question with your new code and explain what doesn't work instead of just saying *"it doesn't work"*. That's not helpful to anyone.

Comment: I did not look for a gameobject in my working code as you did in your answer `GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectScriptAIsAttachedTo");`. I just defind player (a GameObject) as public and asigned it in the inspector and just used the code: `playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();` ofcorse after defining `PlayerHealth playerHealth;` . I tried your answer just now, and it did work, and I found that it's because I used `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");` instead of `GameObject.Find("Player");`. I really don't know how that makes a difference.

Comment: @Programmer anyway I appreciate your advice and will put that in mind.