# How to assign a value from another script variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I accessing another script but her value is by default null.

I want to increase a score when colliding with the obstacle(+5).

Code:

### playerscore.cs

```
public static class playerscore            
{
    public static int Score = 0;   //static variable
}
```

### TouchControll.cs

```
public Text scoretext;

void Awake()
{
   //when I game quit and reenter the game then display the last score
   PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
   
   //this data on my ram not in harddisk 
   playerscore.Score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score); 

   //last score text update when I Reenter the game
   scoretext.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score").ToString();
   print(scoretext.text);
   
   //pass a score one scene to another scene
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
   scoretext.text = ("" + playerscore.Score);
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
     //Debug.Log("oncollisionenter");
     //when my player reaches the finish line then the score add=100; //work fine
     if (col.gameObject.tag == "successfinishtag")
      {
          playerscore.Score += 100;
          PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);    
          scoretext.text = ("" + playerscore.Score);
          //Debug.Log("scoreadd:" + playerscore.Score);
     }
}
```

problem is here
I want the when my player collided with the obstacle then increment my score(+5) but the issue is not increasing my score

### obstacle.cs

```
int incrementscore = 5;

TouchControll touchcontroll; 

void Start()
{
   GetComponent<TouchControll>();
}
//here player colliding with the obstacle
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    foreach (Transform child in transform) 
    {
            //Debug.Log("Inside foreach");
            
            if (child.tag == "obstacleobject")
            {
                Animator anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

                anim.Play("animone");
            }
   }
   playerscore.Score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
   print(playerscore.Score);  
   Debug.Log(touchcontroll);  //null

   if (touchcontroll!= null)//null by default if(null != null) condition false
   {
            IncrementScore();
            

            touchcontroll.scoretext.text = playerscore.Score.ToString();
            
    }
}

    void IncrementScore()
    {
        //Debug.Log("Inside Increment score");
        playerscore.Score = playerscore.Score + incrementscore;

        PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score);
        //print(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", playerscore.Score));

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", playerscore.Score);

        touchcontroll.scoretext.text = playerscore.Score.ToString();
    }
```

I want the when my player collided with the obstacle then increment my score(+5) but the issue is not increasing my score how to solve the problem plz help.

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access variables/functions from another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341408/access-variables-functions-from-another-script)

Comment: @Ruzihm thanks given suggestion I know how to access a variable from another script but I want to assign a value when my player colliding with the obstacle?

Comment: Don't use `PlayerPrefs` at all for saving game progress like points ...

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the result of GetComponent back to anything. Change obstacle.cs:

```
TouchControll touchcontroll; 

void Start()
{
   touchcontroll = GetComponent<TouchControll>();
}
```

However, `GetComponent()` only returns something if there is an instance of whatever object attached to the current game object. Are obstacle.cs and TouchControll.cs both attached to the current GameObject?

If not GetComponent is not going to work, use FindObjectOfType() instead:

```
void Start()
{
   touchcontroll = FindObjectOfType<TouchControll>();
}
```

Here are the relevant pages from Unity scripting API for more info:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Comment: Are obstacle.cs and TouchControll.cs both attached to the current GameObject? No TouchControll.cs attach the player game object and obstacle.cs attach the obstacle game object.

Comment: Ok so GetComponent is not going to work for you then, as it only returns things attached to the current game object. You should use FindObjectOfType as per my example.

Answer (score 0):

I have used in my game this scenario, where Player collide with coin and it increment coin value smoothly in my case. And I have also noticed there is simple difference with your script from me. U have to used FindObjectOfType<> and also have to called public int incrementscore = 5; Where U didn't use any access modifier. Below also include my code, U can take a look and get the idea. Hopefully this will work for U. thanks

```
public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour
{

public int coinValue;
private LevelManager gameLevelManager;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    gameLevelManager = FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    Debug.Log("Triggered");
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        gameLevelManager.AddCoins(coinValue);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}

}
```

//In LevelManager scripts

```
public void AddCoins(int numberOfCoins)
{
    coins += numberOfCoins;
    coinText.text = "Coins : " + coins;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be simply , no use PlayerPrefs to other place

```
public static class playerscore            
{
    public static int Score
    {
        get { return PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score", 0);} 
        set { PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use PlayerPrefs for this. This is like putting your dishes into a box (with plastic peanuts and packing tape) in order to move them from the cupboard to the dining table.