# How to set a get; set; value from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an impostor api plugin and the file GameOptionsData.cs has this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Impostor cooldown to kill in seconds.
    /// </summary>
    public float KillCooldown { get; set; }
```

and I have my own script that has this:

```
if(message[0] == "/cooldown")
        {
            if (message[1] != null)
            {
                int kkd = 0;
                bool CanConvert = int.TryParse(message[1], out kkd);
                if (CanConvert == true)
                {
                    e.PlayerControl.SendChatToPlayerAsync("you would have made the kill cooldown," + kkd + ", but my code is not currently working Sorry!");
                    //Set Cooldown here
                }
                else
                {
                    e.PlayerControl.SendChatToPlayerAsync("This command requires a number \n Example: /cooldown 10");
                }
            }else
            {
                e.PlayerControl.SendChatToPlayerAsync("This command requires a number \n Example: /cooldown 10");
            }
        }
```

and I want to change the KillCooldown value where it says //Set Cooldown here how would I do this I don't know too much about C# so I apologize if this is a stupid question or I am completely thinking about this in the wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: Is the GameOptionsData class extending MonoBehaviour? or is it a plain old class.

Comment: What is ```e```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variables/functions from another Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341408/access-variables-functions-from-another-component)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
//set the cool down
e.Game.Options.KillCooldown = 10;
//sync the cooldown to all clients
e.Game.SyncSettingsAsync();
```